# How can i disable eventValidation in EditForm.aspx in sharepoint 2010

Tags: sharepoint-2010

I am adding new items to a Lookup column Dropdown list with less than 20 items  on an edit form using some javascript.

When I click save I get an error saying
Invalid postback or callback argument.  Event validation is enabled using  in configuration or <%@ Page EnableEventValidation="true" %> in a page.  For security purposes, this feature verifies that arguments to postback or callback events originate from the server control that originally rendered them.  If the data is valid and expected, use the ClientScriptManager.RegisterForEventValidation method in order to register the postback or callback data for validation.

If I add  Page  EnableEventValidation="false" I get a Parser error saying  Description: An error occurred during the parsing of a resource required to service this request. Please review the following specific parse error details and modify your source file appropriately.

Parser Error Message: The enableeventvalidation attribute on the page directive is not allowed in this page.

The eventlog says 
Microsoft.SharePoint.WebPartPages.WebPartPageUserException: The enableeventvalidation attribute on the page directive is not allowed in this page. 
STACKTRACE:
Microsoft.SharePoint.WebPartPages.WebPartPageUserException: The enableeventvalidation attribute on the page directive is not allowed in this page.
 at Microsoft.SharePoint.ApplicationRuntime.SPPageParserFilter.PreprocessDirective(String directiveName, IDictionary attributes)
 at System.Web.UI.TemplateParser.ParseStringInternal(String text, Encoding fileEncoding)

I checked my web.config and it has no pages enableEventValidation

How can I disable eventValidation in sharepoint. [hopefully on a per-page basis]? Or do I have to use infopath?

Answer (score 0):

Setting EnableEventValidation="False" is not a good solution in sharepoint, because it is security feature. I have an experince about modify dropdownlist elements using javascript, and it gives me same error message. I have found the solution for this error by adding method protected override void Render(HtmlTextWriter writer) in code behind.

```
protected override void Render(HtmlTextWriter writer)
{
   //Set Dropdownlist Value
   ddlOption.Add("value");
   base.Render(writer);
}
```